# "Path must include project and resource name" in Eclim when executing some commands

Tags: eclipse, macvim, eclim

I'm using Eclim to develop Java Application, whenever I run command :Validate in MacVim to validate Java Source, it raise exception message:

```
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path must include project and resource name: <Project>
while executing command (port: 9091): -editor vim -command java_src_update -p "<Project>" -f "src/mobile/railsvideos/LoginActivity.java" -v`
```

Any help is appreciated?